# What can I do to make sure my computer isn't infected with FinSpy?

Tags: malware, virus, spyware

What steps have been taken by common free software OS distributions to protect against it?  What can Windows users do?  What ways are there to rid a system of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the string "FinSpy" across all files.

"But their most intriguing finding was a small but telling word embedded in the spyware’s code: “FinSpy.”

That quote is from the article at http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/08/31/how-two-amateur-sleuths-looked-for-finspy-software/

According to that article you could also look for connections to servers answering manual connection attempts with Hallo Steffi".